# Option to minimise console window in HTML/CSS/JS code snippet while answering the question which have code snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

While using  HTML/CSS/JS  code snippet if the code has some console output .The console window takes **major  part of  the screen** at **bottom** and the bottom contents of the code **are  not  visible**.

Say there is a button at  bottom of the browser screen and at the same time a console output so the things get overlapped.

Comment: you can just not show console div in snippet

Comment: @Grundy I am saying when I am actually running the code snippet

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're talking about. The code window is separate from the results window, so the code is always visible. If you mean the bottom part of the *results* is cut off by the console; sure. But in that case, click the full page link.

Comment: I'm not @Grundy, but anyway, yes, it's visible in full page, but it shouldn't cut off the content at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console here in result is a simple `div` with *as-console-wrapper* class. So you can add styles to customize it.

For example: set max-height, add hover style

```js
console.log("This");
console.log("is");
console.log("as");
console.log("example");
console.log("output");
console.log("that");
console.log("takes");
console.log("up");
console.log("a");
console.log("lot");
console.log("of");
console.log("space");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 25px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.as-console-wrapper:hover {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
```

Or  event make a label for console like this

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("This");
  console.log("is");
  console.log("as");
  console.log("example");
  console.log("output");
  console.log("that");
  console.log("takes");
  console.log("up");
  console.log("a");
  console.log("lot");
  console.log("of");
  console.log("space");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(90%);
}
.as-console-wrapper .as-console {
  display: none;
}
.as-console-wrapper::before {
  content: "Console";
  display: block;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.as-console-wrapper:hover {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.as-console-wrapper:hover::before {
  display: none;
}
.as-console-wrapper:hover .as-console {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
```

Comment: this should be available already

Answer (score 2):

A work around in the meantime:

- Right-click on console and "Inspect Element"
- Right-click on the `as-console-wrapper` div
- Delete node

Try it with the snippet below:

```js
console.log("This");
console.log("is");
console.log("as");
console.log("example");
console.log("output");
console.log("that");
console.log("takes");
console.log("up");
console.log("a");
console.log("lot");
console.log("of");
console.log("space");
```

```html
<p>Testy test is for testing.</p>
```

You could also leave a comment for the OP pointing out that they've hidden an important part of their results by including the console and suggest they either hide it or add white space to the bottom of their HTML.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I am saying